# Django + Get Cached data and manipulate

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

how to get the cached data in below extended viewset in django ?

we are using RedisCache

**Base Viewset**

```
class BaseViewSet(ListAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'options']
    permission_classes = [IsAuthorizedUser]

    @method_decorator(cache_page(settings.VIEWSET_CACHE_TIMEOUT))
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(data={"message":"somedata"}
```

**New Viewset**

```
class NewViewSet(BaseViewSet):
    group_permissions = {
        'GET': (
            roles.New,
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For RedisCache we can get all available keys with.

from django.core.cache import cache

cache.keys('*')

then cache.get('keyname')